# Exceeding / bypassing Google Calendar API usage limit

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, service-accounts, google-iam

I am developing a web application that helps users organize their events and guests. I have two types of users:

1. "organizer" - the one who can creates events,
2. "guest" - the one who only attends events.

All data I have about them is only their Google (Gmail) email.

My users are grouped into "teams". In every team, there may be many people who may organize event, but the organizer of specific event is not relevant (every organizer in this team can change every team's event) and not always the whole team is invited to the event.

Every time an organizer creates new event in my application, I want my application to create a representation of this event in Google Calendar. Moreover, I want my app to invite guests to this Google Calendar event, which are the same people who were marked as "guests" in my application. Also, I don't want let the organizer edit Google Calendar event directly (I want the organizer to edit the event in my application first) and I want the events to be visible only for organizer and his guests. I expect thousands of events / month, with 1-30 guests each. If possible, I would rather not make my users connect their Google Calendar with my application using OAuth2.

How can I do this without hitting usage limits?

---

My current solution works this way:

1. I created an Google Cloud Platform account and activated Google Calendar API
2. I created a Service Account with IAM
3. I'm using single Service Account to all events, where my Service Account is host of every Google Calendar event and both organizers/guests are attendees.

This worked seamlessly, but after some time (and getting more users) I eventually hit "Usage limit exceeded" error. According to [this support article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en), limits are quite low (mostly 10k invites are much less than I would like to do).

Comment: As stated in the reference you provided: "To prevent spamming, Google Calendar limits the number of invitations a user sends to external guests". You must agree that 10 000 users is a lot - especially since it's not per month, but replenishes after few days and it is only the case for external suers, for your domain users the limit is higher.

Comment: Yes, 10 000 is a lot, but the core of my application are events - it's all about that. So when I have 40 "organizers" users, each of them wants to create an event per day and invite 10 people, then 40*30*10 and I already hit the limit; and having 40 users is not that much. This is why I'm wondering if there's any other option for integration with Google Calendar

Comment: You can try to set-up a second service account (or even acquire a second GSuite account) and implement in your code that if the usage of the first service account results in an error, the request is tried again with the second account.